# Not showing OSSEC agent actual IP address on manager server

Tags: xml, amazon-web-services, devops, ossec

I added a new agent on the Manager server using `ossec-authd` method which registers an agent IP on the manager server without interactive prompt input. I am able to add an agent on the manager server but it showing the agent IP address as `IP: any`. I would like to see the agent's actual IP address like `IP: X.X.X.X` instead of `IP: any`. Is there any possible solution to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I upgraded our OSSEC version on the manager.  I fixed it by using the '-i' option when ossec-authd starts up.

```
/var/ossec/bin/ossec-authd -i -p 1515
```